# How can I sync the data of multiple pods having their own PV in k8's?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, sbt, akka-http

I deploy an `elasticsearch:8.4.3` using `StatefuSet` having **Two replicas**. The app deployed and in running state, when I insert the data using Postman the data inserted successfully, but when I try to get the data it generate `An error occurred: [es/get] failed: [index_not_found_exception] no such index [user]` as there are two pods having their own PV so `loadbalancer` send the request to get the data to the pod which may or may not have any data , after multiple try I got the data because the request sent to the pod which stored that data.

My question is that , is there anyway to sync the data of both pod, can we limit the write permission to only a single pod and then sync the data to all the pod so that we can search it from any pod.
I'm new to k8's, need your help.

here are the yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: elastic-stateful

spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elastic-label
  template:
    metadata:
      name: elastic-pod
      labels:
        app: elastic-label
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: elastic-container
          image: elasticsearch:8.4.3
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9200
          env:
            - name: discovery.type
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: elasticsearch-configmap
                  key: es.discovery.type
            - name: xpack.security.enabled
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: elasticsearch-configmap
                  key: es.xpack.security.enabled
            - name: xpack.security.enrollment.enabled
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: elasticsearch-configmap
                  key: es.xpack.security.enrollment.enabled
            - name: xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: elasticsearch-configmap
                  key: es.xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled
          volumeMounts:
            - name: elastic-pvc
              mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: elastic-pvc
      spec:
        accessModes: [ "ReadWriteMany" ]
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi


---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: elastic-service

spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: elastic-label
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 9200
      targetPort: 9200
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: akka-service

spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: akka-label
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8083
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're looking for how to create an Elasticsearch cluster.

Add two more env as well in your pod's yaml:

```yaml
          env:
            - name: discovery.seed_hosts
              value: "pod1.headless-svc.ns.svc, pod2.headless-svc.ns.svc" # pod's dns address  
            - name: cluster.initial_master_nodes
              value: "pod1.headless-svc.ns.svc" # master pod's dns address
```

Ref: [Discovery and cluster formation settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/important-settings.html#discovery-settings)

Btw, you need to create a headless service with `clusterIP: None` for generating pod's dns address.